# Load script file on demand with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, loading

I use an accordion or tabs. When clicking on a tab, I want to display a map or something that require a big javascript file to load.

To not load the big javascript when it is not needed, I want to load it only when the tab is clicked.

How can I do that? I've created a good starting point with accordion and a click event.

- I use vanilla js (pure javascript - no jQuery)
- I use it on a webpage (not nodejs)
- I'm fine if it works with modern browsers (IE not needed)

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('[data-trigger]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Load script from file');
    // CDN example - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mapbox-gl/1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' height='24'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' d='M0 0h24v24H0z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M13.172 12l-4.95-4.95 1.414-1.414L16 12l-6.364 6.364-1.414-1.414z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ h2 label:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

p {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ h2 ~ p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="faq-1">
    <h2 data-trigger>
      <label for="faq-1">Click to load map</label>
    </h2>
    <p>Gummies marzipan croissant chupa chups.</p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="faq-2">
    <h2>
      <label for="faq-2">Something else</label>
    </h2>
    <p>Cookie bear claw carrot cake croissant.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try document.write? or
let myScript = document.createElement("script");
myScript.setAttribute("src", "https://www.example.com/foo.js");
document.body.appendChild(myScript);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're comfortable with only supporting modern browsers, you could use the [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) function to load the file:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('[data-trigger]').addEventListener('click', async() => {
    const module = await import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mapbox-gl/1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js');
    console.log(`module is loaded: ${Object.keys(mapboxgl)}`);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' height='24'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' d='M0 0h24v24H0z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M13.172 12l-4.95-4.95 1.414-1.414L16 12l-6.364 6.364-1.414-1.414z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~h2 label:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

p {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~h2~p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="faq-1">
    <h2 data-trigger>
      <label for="faq-1">Click to load map</label>
    </h2>
    <p>Gummies marzipan croissant chupa chups.</p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="faq-2">
    <h2>
      <label for="faq-2">Something else</label>
    </h2>
    <p>Cookie bear claw carrot cake croissant.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`import()` returns a promise which is resolved on successful fetch, and resolves immediately on subsequent calls (in my testing), so you wouldn't have to deal with that specifically.

For your specific `mapbox-gl` script, the value returned won't be useful, as the script isn't written as an ES6 module, but the side-effects of the script running will be in place (in this case, the `mapboxgl` variable being assigned onto `globalThis`). In scenarios where the loaded script is a module (using `export` correctly), you can use the resolved value directly to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You could dynamically create a script tag and add it to the document whenever the button is pressed. This will trigger the script to immediately be loaded. With the `onload` callback you can run your code, like creating a map, the moment the script has actually loaded.

Do add `{ once: true }` as the third parameter for `addEventListener` as it will ensure that the trigger can only be clicked once and won't be able to append the script more than once.

```
function createMap() {
  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    ...
  });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('[data-trigger]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Load script from file');
    
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = 'mapboxgljs';
    script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mapbox-gl/1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js'
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = function() {
      console.log('script loaded, you can use it now.');
      createMap();
    }
    document.body.append(script);
  }, { once: true }); // Make sure that the button can only be pressed once.
});
```

Comment: adding a `script.defer = true` or `async` would  be beneficial too. we want the page to be reactive during script load

Comment: Good addition. `async` would the way to go as `defer` implies to load it **after** every other script that isn't deferred.